# webpack-cli@3.0.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Having a little trouble with React. Does anyone know how I can install the peer of webpack@^4.x.x?

This is the error I am recieving when I try to run

```
webpack-dev-server
```

in cmd. It just returns

```
webpack-cli@3.0.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` has Webpack as a [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/), which means that you are responsible for installing that yourself.

You could install the latest version of Webpack and add it to your `devDependencies` with the following command:

```
npm i -D webpack@latest
```

By writing `webpack-dev-server` you are also trying to use the globally installed version of that package. You can use the locally installed one instead by adding it to a script in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts" : {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need `webpack` updated globally to the latest version, you can run:

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Comment: What if that doesn't help? I installed webpack 4.42.0 globally, but webpack-cli doesn't see it...

# npm list -g webpack
/usr/local/lib
└── webpack@4.42.0

# npm install -g webpack-cli
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.11 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none was installed.

Comment: Come to think of it, what kind of semver is "4.x.x"? Shouldn't this be "^4.0.0" or something?